# Structuring JSON to loop through in Django View

Tags: python, json, django

I'm using Axios to POST a request to a Django route.

The JSON is structured as follows:

```
{
    "blanks": {
        {
            "id": 1,
            "sizes": {
                "id": 1,
                "size": "SM"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "sizes": {
                "id": 1,
                "size": "SM"
            }
        }
    },
    "locations": {
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Philadelphia"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Boston"
        },
    }
}
```

I'm trying to loop through each of the objects within `locations`, and perform an action on them. My Django function is as follows:

```
def order_new_store(request):

    post_unicode = request.body.decode('utf-8')
    post = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))

    for location in post['locations'].items():
        #etc
```

However, my app is throwing the following error:

`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'`

Is there a way that I can restructure either my JSON, or my loop, so that I can grab a subset of the JSON object and loop through it?

Comment: Probably it is `location: [ ... ]`, not `location: { ... }` in the JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error specifies that the `location` key does *not* map to a dictionary, but a list, a list of dictionaries. So the loop should iterate like:

```
for location in post['locations']:  # no .items()
    loc_id = location['id']
    loc_name = location['name']
    # ...
```

So here `location` is a subdictionary, a dictionary that - based on the posted JSON sample - has an `id` and `name` key. We can for example obtain these items, and do further processing.